# Condition in first Borel-Cantelli Lemma cannot be weakened?

Tags: probability

Exercise 1.1.1 (p. 14) in Terence Tao's *Topics in Random Matrix Theory* is

> Let $E_1, E_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of events such that 
>   $\sum_i P(E_i) < \infty$. Show that almost surely, at most finitely
>   many of the events occur at once. State and prove a result to the effect
>   that the condition $\sum_i P(E_i) < \infty$ cannot be weakened.

My question is about the second part of the exercise. It seems to me that the result to be stated must be

> If $\sum_i P(E_i) = \infty$ then there is strictly positive probability that
>   an infinite number of the events $E_i$ occur.

But this cannot be true: take $X$ to be a random variable uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ and $E_i = \{X \le 1/i\}$.

Of course with independence we have the second Borel-Cantelli lemma. But is there some way to answer the second half of the exercise without invoking independence?

Comment: One weakening is: Let $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$ be real numbers for $i= 1,2,3,\ldots$ with $\sum_ip_i = \infty$. Then there exists a probability space with events $E_i$, such that $P(E_i) = p_i$ and there is strictly positive probability that an infinite number of the events $E_i$ occur. I don't know if this weakening is true or not.

Comment: @AlexZorn Of course it does since one can realize the events E_i as being independent.

Comment: @AlexZorn And, using an explicit construction, the conclusion can be strenghtened to $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}E_n=\Omega.$$

Answer (score 0):

**An intuitive approach**

(The tail of the walking intervals)

Consider $([0,1],\mathscr B, \text{Leb})$ and an infinite sequence of intervals  $\{E_n=[a_n,b_n)\}$ such that $$0=a_0<b_0=a_1<b_1=a_2<b_2=\cdots =a_{k-1}<b_{k-1}=a_k<b_k=1=$$
$$=b_{k+1}>a_{k+1}=b_{k+2}>a_{k+2}=\cdots =b_{k'-1}>a_{k'-1}=b_{k'}>a_{k'}=0=$$
$$=a_{k'+1}<b_{k'+1}=a_{k'+2}<\cdots$$

The first $k+1$ intervals cover $[0,1]$, so to speak, from the left to the right, then the next sub sequence (form the $k+1^{th}$ to the $k'^{th}$) covers $[0,1]$ from the right to the left, and again and again. So, picture walking intervals that turn around when reaching $1$ or $0$.

If we do not restrict the length of the consequtive intervals but keep it positive then this system of walking intervals models a sequence of events whose members may or may not occur infinitely many times for any $\omega\in[0,1].$

Let us regulate the length of the intervals in such a way that the next interval is always shorter than the previous one. If $\lambda_k>0$ denotes the length of the $k^{th}$ interval then there are  two possibilities. Either

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lambda_i=\infty$$

or

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lambda_i<\infty.$$

In the first case the walking intervals will walk back and forth forever while in the second case the intervals cannot walk forever because they do not have enough total length.

This is how the number of occurrences of certain events  is related to the sum of their measure. If the sum of the measure of our events is infinite then the example of the walking intervals will show that the number of occurrences can  be infinite.